# ckeditor5 mathtype fraction issue

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5, mathtype, wiris

We are using ckediter 5 with wiris mathtype module getting issue while putting fraction values. like 32/3 is converted to 3⅔.

ck editer angular version :  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.1"
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^24.0.0",
"@wiris/mathtype-ckeditor5": "^7.24.4",

if i am upgrading version it causes issue

Error: node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/observablemixin.d.ts:8:10 - error TS2614: Module '"./emittermixin"' has no exported member 'type'. Did you mean to use 'import type from "./emittermixin"' instead?

8 import { type Emitter } from './emittermixin';
~~~~

Error: node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/observablemixin.d.ts:8:15 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

8 import { type Emitter } from './emittermixin';

**Any Idea how to resolve this in anguar **

I am giving output 32/3 and getting output 3⅔
fraction issues of ckediter

Comment: https://github.com/wiris/html-integrations/tree/stable/demos/angular/ckeditor5
I had tried this also but getting same fraction issue

Comment: Can you please formay your code snippets as code so that the question reads more cleanly for potential answerers?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem
I have to write allowJs true inside compileroption inside  tsconfig.json file
and this issue had been resolved in the higher versions of ckeditor use latest version

refer this project for more
https://github.com/mustafagaut/mathmlangular